# Python 3.6 isn't runnable through Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10

### Problem:

I have included Python's install path (C:\Program Files\Python36) on both 
the "Path" and "PYTHONPATH" system variables. I haven't needed to use Python for a while, and I am certain it worked last time (close to a few months ago). Python IDLE still works, but I need to use Python through the command prompt.

Every other similar question I found online was usually resolved with making the proper changes to the system variables.

Error message when attempting to execute any Python-related task:

`python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

### What I've done so far:

- Set system variables to Python Path via Control Panel>System and Security>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables
- Tried using `cd` to use python directly from it's install location

Comment: Edit your question to include the command you tried and the full result error message.  Otherwise we're just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: Please include those variables as well as listing where python is installed. Make sure you reset the terminal after changing said variables if doing so globally.

Comment: Are you setting them through the Windows environment dialog box, or at the command prompt?  Are you using SET or SETX?  Which version of Windows is this?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I am new to stack exchange, but that is not a good excuse regardless. However, I was able to answer my own question. See below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Solution:

Python's install path was overridden by Visual Studio to it's "shared" location (more like pain-in-the-ass location) located at:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\`

Changing both system variables(`Path` and <del>`PYTHONPATH`</del>) to this location resolved this issue.

Thank you to all who commented/responded.

EDIT: Apparently it is bad practice to manually set `PYTHONPATH`, as it is automatically set by Python.

Comment: Research PyLauncher (Py.exe). It is already in the path, and can run any version of python on your system that is registered.

Comment: Never add Python's installation directory or standard library directories to `PYTHONPATH`. Those directories are added to `sys.path` automatically.  Adding them manually to `PYTHONPATH` will just cause problems with other Python installations, for zero benefit. Also, for the same reason, never set `PYTHONHOME` for a standard installation.